# How to indent line like normal IDE

Tags: emacs

Emacs doesn't automatically indent line for me. For example:

```
int main() {
   int a;
int b; // this line still don't indent with int a
}
```

So, how to indent line in Emacs ? And moreover, each time I type `{`, how to make Emacs automatically indent a tab like other IDEs (eclipse, netbean ...) ?

Comment: @ close voter: please give me comment which problem in my post ? Also duplicate ? Or not suitable for `StackOverFlow` ? Or just simple, when first close vote, you will have a winter hat ?

Comment: ⁺¹, I'd also wanted to see a reason why the question was considered to be an offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs normal behaviour is to reserve the <kbd>RET</kbd> (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) key for inserting the carriage return literally, while it uses <kbd>C-j</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) for entering and indenting. This is also so because of a range of other keys that can cause line to be re-indented. By tradition, the commands that cause re-indentation have "electric" as part of their name. `c-mode` has a bunch of "electric" commands. To find them, when editing a C source, you can do:

- <kbd>C-h b</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>) - list all key bindings in the buffer.
- <kbd>M-s o</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> PC or <kbd>Option</kbd> Mac + <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd>) - invoke `occur` command, alternatively, you can <kbd>M-x</kbd>`occur`.
- Type "electric" when `occur` prompts you for input (after the previous step, the point will be in minibuffer, so just continue typing).

It will open an additional buffer with the content similar to this:

```
12 matches for "electric" in buffer: *Help*
    706:C-d             c-electric-delete-forward
    709:#               c-electric-pound
    710:( .. )          c-electric-paren
    711:*               c-electric-star
    712:,               c-electric-semi&comma
    713:/               c-electric-slash
    714::               c-electric-colon
    715:;               c-electric-semi&comma
    716:{               c-electric-brace
    717:}               c-electric-brace
    718:DEL             c-electric-backspace
    726:C-c C-l         c-toggle-electric-state
```

This lists all the commands and the keys assigned to them, which do some "electric" action. You can move point to any of them and by pressing <kbd>C-h f</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) <kbd>RET</kbd> it will open the help page describing what exactly the command does. For example, if you request help on `c-electric-colon` it will show you this:

```
c-electric-colon is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`cc-cmds.el'.

(c-electric-colon ARG)

Insert a colon.

If `c-electric-flag' is non-nil, the colon is not inside a literal and a
numeric ARG hasn't been supplied, the command performs several electric
actions:

(a) If the auto-newline feature is turned on (indicated by "/la" on
the mode line) newlines are inserted before and after the colon based on
the settings in `c-hanging-colons-alist'.

(b) Any auto-newlines are indented.  The original line is also
reindented unless `c-syntactic-indentation' is nil.

(c) If auto-newline is turned on, whitespace between two colons will be
"cleaned up" leaving a scope operator, if this action is set in
`c-cleanup-list'.

[back]
```

You can continue reading the manual from here by moving the point to the item which looks like a hyperlink (usually it is underlined, or has different visual appearance, then the rest of the text), and hit <kbd>RET</kbd>. You can use <kbd>C-b</kbd> and <kbd>C-f</kbd> in `*Help*` mode to navigate back and forward between the pages you've already visited (or move the point to the `[back]` or `[forward]` buttons and press <kbd>RET</kbd>).

Comment: When I use: `M-x occur` it will appear line: `List lines matching regexp (default occur:)`, and in "result windows", doesn't have `... matches for "electric" in buffer` as I see in your example :(

Comment: I do as this step: `M-x occur RET`. Emacs comes to line: `List lines matching regxp`,  I type `electric`. Emacs notices : `Search 1 buffer` --> `No match found` --> `You can run command occur with M-s o`. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to autoindent only C code put this in your `.emacs` file:

```
(defun enable-newline-and-indent ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))
(add-hook 'c-mode 'enable-newline-and-indent)
```

Alternatively you can enable this behaviour for all programming modes like this (it will work only in Emacs 24+):

```
(defun enable-newline-and-indent ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))
(add-hook 'prog-mode 'enable-newline-and-indent)
```

Yet another option would be the use of the `electric-indent-mode` and `electric-layout-mode` introduced in Emacs 24 - they will basically trigger newline or indent after some characters like `;` and `{`.

Comment: Nitpick: `electric-indent-mode` only triggers an indent, not a newline.  It's `electric-layout-mode` which sometimes adds newlines.